# How to convert "1985-02-07T00:00:00.000Z" (ISO8601) to a date value in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp

I tried to convert a time-stamp ("1985-02-07T00:00:00.000Z") to a date and I failed to succeed in my several different attempts.

Below is the query I have tried:

```
 select to_date('1985-02-07T00:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.fffZ')
 from dual;
```

Your suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 for trying stuff. You can make the question better by including what the results were and how they were wrong or what generally didn't work. (Was there an error? Was the date a few hours off?)

Comment: According to [to_date](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) I believe that at least "fff" is wrong and should be "FF3". But I don't use/have Oracle :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`to_date` converts the input to a `DATE` type which does not support fractional seconds. To use fractional seconds you need to use a `TIMESTAMP` type which is created when using `to_timestamp`

pst's comment about the `ff3` modifier is also correct.

"Constant" values in the format mask need to be enclosed in double quote

So the final statement is:

```
select to_timestamp('1985-02-07T00:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
SQL> select cast(to_timestamp('1985-02-07T00:00:00.000Z', 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"') as date)
  2    from dual
  3  /

CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('
-------------------
07-02-1985 00:00:00

1 row selected.
```

Answer (score 5):

Some [rules to follow](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i34924):

1. Literals must be double-quoted: `MM` expects a month number, `"MM"` expects a double-M.
2. The format for fractional seconds is `FF`, not `F` or `FFF`. You specify the number of digits with a trailing integer, e.g. `FF3`.
3. But dates cannot hold fractional seconds anyway so you cannot use `FF3` in this context.

This works:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('1985-02-07T00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
FROM dual;
```

I don't know if there's a way to ignore fractional seconds in `TO_DATE()` so I've used string manipulation functions to strip them out:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR('1985-02-07T00:00:00.000Z', 1, 19), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT to_timestamp_tz('2012-08-08T09:06:14.000-07:00','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZR')
FROM dual;

External table DDL,
extract_date char(29) DATE_FORMAT timestamp WITH TIMEZONE mask 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZR'
```

Comment: nice use of the _tz function.  I had to use this though: 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZHTZM'

Answer (score -1):

if u want to get the string in datetime format then try this....

```
select to_char(TO_DATE('2012-06-26T00:00:00.809Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS".""ZZZZ"'),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss PM') as EVENT_DATE from dual

EVENT_DATE
-----------------------
2012-06-26 12:06:00 AM
```

only for date simply use...

```
select TO_DATE('2012-01-06T00:00:00.809Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS".""ZZZZ"') from dual
```