# Need a Date format which supports in JAVA as well as Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, date

I need a date format in 24 hours along with minutes,
that date format should work in both JAVA as well as Oracle.
Can any one please suggest some date format which will helpful for me.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

I would think the oracle jdbc-driver handles this for you, but if you need more control, the best choice is probably [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). This can be converted to java as described here:

- [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

And to oracle as described here:

- [How to convert "1985-02-07T00:00:00.000Z" (ISO8601) to a date value in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654292/how-to-convert-1985-02-07t000000-000z-iso8601-to-a-date-value-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

the format would be yyyy-mm-dd
where y is for year,m is for month and d is for date

Comment: please specify hours and minutes also along with date