# Oracle: How can I specify character literals in TO_DATE conversions?

Tags: oracle, date

How do I specify character literals in a date specification?  In the second example, I would like to skip the T and Z.

```
select to_date('2015-04-06 19:56:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;

    2015-04-06 19:56:30                                  

select to_date('2015-04-06 19:56:30', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ') from dual;

    ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert "1985-02-07T00:00:00.000Z" (ISO8601) to a date value in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654292/how-to-convert-1985-02-07t000000-000z-iso8601-to-a-date-value-in-oracle)

Comment: The answer may be the same ("use double quotes") but the question is different.  It's not obvious reading the manual how to specify character literals.

Comment: Well, regarding quoting literals in Oracle, it is the same good old way to use double-quotation marks. Which works in the date format too. Regarding the duplicate question, I just pasted your date format in google, and that SO link came at very first in Google ;-)

Comment: Yeah, well the documentation could do a better job in specifying that, because I read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132 and associated and couldn't find it.  Congratulations on your google skills, but I wasn't concerned are about the specific date format, I was concerned about how to_date quotes literal characters.

Comment: It is documented http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA. I added this as an answer so that it is visible to others clearly. Thanks for pointing this out, I revisited the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enclose the literals in double quotes:

```
SQL> select to_date('2015-04-06T19:56:30Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"') from dual;

TO_DATE('2015-04-0
------------------
06-APR-15
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation,

[Punctuation and Character Literals in Datetime Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA)

> You can include these characters in a date format model:
>
> - Punctuation such as hyphens, slashes, commas, periods, and colons
> - **Character literals, enclosed in double quotation marks**
>
> These characters appear in the return value in the same location as
>   they appear in the format model.

Following the documentation, **enclosing the character literals in double-quotation marks will work in the format model.**

```
TO_DATE('2015-04-06T19:56:30Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')
```