# What is the date format used in date string, '2019-01-21T19:02:25Z'

Tags: sql, oracle, iso8601, sql-date-functions

I am not able to obtain the date object from date string **2019-01-21T19:02:25Z**

```
select to_char(to_date('2019-01-21T19:02:25Z','yyyy-mm-ddThh24:mi:ssZ'),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

yields

> ORA-01821: date format not recognized
>   01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

May I know what date format is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert "1985-02-07T00:00:00.000Z" (ISO8601) to a date value in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654292/how-to-convert-1985-02-07t000000-000z-iso8601-to-a-date-value-in-oracle)  This is DEFINITELY oracle. `ORA-12345` is the giveaway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use quotes to match the `T` and `Z` as literals:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(
           '2019-01-21T19:02:25Z',
            'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss"Z"'
         ),
         'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

or, match the `T` as a literal and use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` with the `TZH` and `TZM` format models to match the time zone hours and minutes components (or, instead, `TZR` to match the time zone region):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
           '2019-01-21T19:02:25Z',
            'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ssTZHTZM'
         ),
         'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=29942b83b9402d3490654f2e38489e52)

Comment: Is it somewhere documented or is it a hidden feature that `"Z"` is recognized as shortcut for `+00:00`, resp. `UTC`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Z is short for [Zulu time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z) which is the military equivalent of UTC.

Comment: Yes, I know "Z" means "Zulu time" - I am just not aware that Oracle would know this also. At least timezone `Z` is not listed in `V_$TIMEZONE_NAMES`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That would be a great thing to ask in a separate question as you may get other people who are able to give you an answer (it isn't mentioned in the Format Models documentation).